# Genymotion overrides dhcp of virtualbox network adapter

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I am running an android image with genymotion 2.8.0 and virtualbox 5.0.28 on osx. My network has a router with dhcp 192.168.1.1 and I want to access my host system (the mac) from android by using 10.0.2.3 or the IP of the MAC. The problem is that the virtual network adapter is always getting an ip in the wrong net vboxnet1 => inet 192.168.57.1
Therefore I tried to changed the interface by setting the dhcp settings. Now every time when I do start the image with genymotion the dhcp settings are getting overridden as show in the screenshot.

So how can I persist the dhcp settings?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## The Cause of the Problem

Genymotion is rewriting your network settings in VirtualBox because it has it's own way to handle network connection. That is due to the fact that Genymotion needs to make the android emulator think it has a cellular network or WiFi connection.

### Defining Network Through Genymotion Settings

Because you said that Genymotion keeps resetting your VirtualBox's network configurations, I think it might have something to do with Genymotion's own network configuration.
In order to define your network setting in Genymotion, you need to do the following:
Open Genymotion => `Settings` => `Network` tab. You will get the following screen and in there you need to enable `HTTP Proxy`: [image: Genymotion Network Settings]
It is called a proxy, but it is supposed to work as kind of a "bridge" between your machine's DHCP and the emulator.
You might need to define the connection inside android system too, *depending on the case*.
If so, inside the emulator itself, go to: `Settings` => `Wi-Fi` => Long Click on `WiredSSID` => `Modify network` => `Advanced options` and modify the setting there too accordingly.

---

If that's not helping, you might need to change the specific setting of your emulator's virtual box:

### Network Configuration via Virtualbox Settings

Genymotion uses two different kinds of network configurations in VirtualBox in order to operate.

1. An internal and technical network (defined in `Network` =>
   `Adapter 1` of VirtualBox settings) that helps Genymotion to display
   the virtual device screen or forward events (clicks or widgets) to
   the virtual device.  This network configuration needs to remain untouched. Changing this may prevent Genymotion to run properly.
2. A network simulating access to your local network and to the Internet (defined in `Network` => `Adapter 2` of VirtualBox settings). This network configuration is the one responsible for the emulator's internet connection.

So, you can configure `Network` => `Adapter 2` of VirtualBox settings as desired, according to the following cases:

- Use **`NAT`**, if you are using Genymotion on your local machine.
- Use **`Bridged Adapter`**, if you need your virtual device to use an IP address of your local network (a DHCP server in your local network is required).

You will need to choose the `Bridged Adapter` option, in your case.
Make sure to change that setting in your specific VirtualBox device.

Comment: I thought it had something to do with Genymotion's own network configurations because you said Genymotion keeps resetting the network configurations of VirtualBox. Genymotion uses the "proxy" term to define your desired network port, and I thought it might help if you redirect it to your `DHCP Server Address`. Now I realized that in order to define your DHCP you might need to change the specific emulator's settings instead of the entire VirtualBox's settings. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. But this is exactly the configuration I have (as documented in the genymotion docs). As I described in the question, the problem ist that the bridged adapter is not getting the right IP because it is in the wrong net.
It must be in 192.168.1.* and not  192.168.57.* but the dhcp setting are getting overwritten all the time.

Comment: So what I have to insert in http proxy?